# Print selected index item

Tags: vb.net, printing

I try to print selected index item but I couldnt succeed.

Could you please help me for fixing the codes?

I get "-1" value on the printed page.

```
Private Sub Textbox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged

    Dim idx As Integer = ListBox1.FindStringExact(TextBox2.Text)
                    If idx <> -1 Then
                        ListBox1.SelectedIndex = idx
                        ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.Text)
                        ListBox1.Items.Remove(TextBox2.Text)
                        PrintDoc.Print()
    End sub

Private Sub PrintDoc_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDoc.PrintPage
        Dim drawfont As New Font("arial", 16)
        Dim drawbrush As New SolidBrush(Color.Black)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(ListBox1.SelectedIndex, drawfont, drawbrush, 100, 100)
    End Sub
```

Comment: Did you get any error? What means "no success"?

Comment: What happened? What is supposed to happen?

Comment: printed value show as "-1" on the printed page.

Comment: Well, you're missing an End If but you are also removing that item from the listbox and then seemingly trying to use it in the printdoc (so the selectedindex becomes -1 at that point). Also, undesirable result will occur in the TextChanged method if you were to have a list containing something like Beth and Bethany and you're wanting to print on Bethany. Using the TextChanged will trigger the printdoc on Beth while you're typing out Bethany.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://watchmynewvideoxyz.blogspot.in/2017/02/user3900603-your-answer.html

go there your code ready

if ok make me +1

Comment: you have to remove after print

Comment: I tried your code and its work.I would remove listbox item after print.now I understand.Thanks for help...